# Iron Maiden's Eddie and Tolkien's Gollum

Tags: rock

Rigg's first offical Eddie was used on Maiden's 1980 'Running Free'. In Wall's autobiography, it is said that this was from a design given to Dave Beasley.

Ralph Bakshi released his 'Lord of the Rings' in 1978 and although it wasn't monsterous succes, it had a lot of underground buzz.

Given how close the album is to the film, and that Eddie on 'Running Free' is quite different from later iterations, I realize there may be no connection at all.

That being said, I was wondering if anyone knows if Tolkien/Bakshi's Gollum had any known influence into Eddie's design?[image: Bakshi's Gollum]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the **Running Free** artwork was the first officially *released* depiction of Eddie, it was not Riggs' first iteration of him. The version of Eddie on the self-titled **Iron Maiden** album is the original version. It was selected from pre-existing work by Riggs. The depiction of Eddie in the **Running Free** artwork came afterwards and his face was purposely obscured in shadow so as not to "spoil" Eddie in all his glory on the upcoming album cover.

This original Eddie, while *slightly* similar, bears less of a resemblance to the Gollum artwork:
[image]

Derek Riggs states in the **12 Wasted Years** documentary that the inspiration for the original artwork came from the sight of a human head attached to a Vietnamese tank. His statements occur at ~35:45 in the documentary and can be viewed [here](https://youtu.be/1AZKGwyoiAI?t=2145).

And, that original version of Eddie does more closely resemble typical depictions of decomposing humans (even decades before the Riggs artwork existed):
[image]

Obviously, many things inspire and influence artists, so anything is possible. However, a connection between Eddie and this Gollum depiction is highly unlikely.

Comment: Rich Jackson: THAT was an AWESOME answer! Thanks for it and the links :-)